# Is what I need two PivotTables for possible with just one?

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a spreadsheet with data similar to this:

```
Ticket,    Date,   Priority,  Duration  
1,        1/1/2013,    2,        120  
2,        2/6/2013,    3,         40  
3,       2/10/2013,    1,         90  
4,        3/7/2013,    3,        100  
5,       5/24/2013,    4,        200  
6,       5/31/2013,    1,        190  
7,       6/10/2013,    2,        200
```

and I would like to create a pivot table to show the number of tickets by priority by month and the average duration by month, like so:

```
Month High Medium Urgent Low Average  
Jan    1     0      0     0     120  
Feb    0     2      3     0      65  
Mar    0     4      0     0     100  
May    0     0      6     5     195  
Jun    7     0      0     0     200
```

I can only manage to do this by using two pivot tables however I am interested to know if it can be done by using just a single pivot table.

Comment: You can do it in a single PivotTable, but you'll need to calculate some values first, like the month and convert the priority values to text. What's left is that excel's pivot table automatically sorts the priority text in alphabetical order, but if that's not a problem...

Answer (score 1):

In one PT:

[image: SO21372316 example]

This is with:

1. grouping of `date` by month
2. hiding some columns
3. manual addition of 'Month' and priorities in PT
4. manually reordering the priorities
5. setting the PivotTable Options..., Format, For empty cells show:  to `0`
6. Totals & Filters, Grand Totals, Show grand totals for rows checked and Show grand totals for columns unchecked.